# c++ operator < overload with class and interface

Tags: c++, class, interface, abstract-class, operator-keyword

I am currently working on a project that reads postcodes from a .csv file, completes a haversine calculation and stores items in a list based on a returned search radius. The postcode variables are defined via a class and uses an interface to impliment in main.cpp

The method that has thrown this all out of place is the operator < overload to provide alphabetical sorting of the postcodes (to be used to sort the list in main.cpp)

Postcode class;

```
#ifndef POSTCODE_H_
#define POSTCODE_H_
#include <stdexcept>      // std::out_of_range
#include "IPostCode.h"
#include <string>


class PostCode : public IPostCode {


private:
    int Id;
    std::string Postcode;
    std::string firstTwoChars;
    double Lattitude;
    double Longitude;
    double distanceFromCentre;


public:

    PostCode();
    int getId() override;
    std::string getPostcode() override;
    std::string getFirstTwoChars() override;
    double getLattitude() override;
    double getLongitude() override;
    double getdistanceFromCentre() override;
    bool operator<(const PostCode& right) const override;

    void setId(std::string newId) override;
    void setPostcode(std::string newPostcode) override;

    void setLattitude(std::string newLattitude) override;
    void setLongitude(std::string newLongitude) override;
    void setdistanceFromCentre(double newdistanceFromCentre) override;  
    void clearPostCode() override;
};

PostCode::PostCode() {
    this->Id = 0;
    this->Postcode = "";
    this->Lattitude = 0.0f;
    this->Longitude = 0.0f;

}

int PostCode::getId()
{
    return this->Id;
}

std::string PostCode::getPostcode()
{
    return this->Postcode;
}

std::string PostCode::getFirstTwoChars()
{
    firstTwoChars = Postcode.substr(0, 2);
    return this->firstTwoChars;
}

double PostCode::getLattitude()
{
    return this->Lattitude;
}

double PostCode::getLongitude()
{
    return this->Longitude;
}

double PostCode::getdistanceFromCentre()
{
    return this->distanceFromCentre;
}

void PostCode::setId(std::string newId)
{
    this->Id = std::stoi(newId);
}

void PostCode::setPostcode(std::string newPostcode)
{
    this->Postcode = newPostcode;
}

void PostCode::setLattitude(std::string newLattitude)
{
    this->Lattitude = std::stod(newLattitude);
}

void PostCode::setLongitude(std::string newLongitude)
{
    this->Longitude = std::stod(newLongitude);
}

void PostCode::setdistanceFromCentre(double newdistanceFromCentre)
{
    this->distanceFromCentre = newdistanceFromCentre;
}

void PostCode::clearPostCode() {
    this->Id = 0;
    this->Postcode = "";
    this->Lattitude = 0.0f;
    this->Longitude = 0.0f;
}
bool PostCode::operator<(const PostCode& right) const
{
    return (Postcode.compare(right.Postcode) < 0);
}
#endif
```

Interface code;

```
#ifndef IPOSTCODE_H_
#define IPOSTCODE_H_

#include <string>

class IPostCode {

public:
    virtual int getId() = 0;
    virtual std::string getPostcode() = 0;
    virtual double getLattitude() = 0;
    virtual double getLongitude() = 0;
    virtual double getdistanceFromCentre() = 0;
    virtual std::string getFirstTwoChars() = 0;
    virtual bool operator<(const PostCode& right) const = 0;

    virtual void setId(std::string newId) = 0;
    virtual void setPostcode(std::string newPostcode) = 0;
    virtual void setLattitude(std::string newLattitude) = 0;
    virtual void setLongitude(std::string newLongitude) = 0;    
    virtual void setdistanceFromCentre(double newdistanceFromCentre) = 0;

    virtual void clearPostCode() = 0;
};
#endif
```

**Errors.**

```
1. Error    C2259   'PostCode': cannot instantiate abstract class   (This error is for the main.cpp declaration of a PostCode)  
2. Error    C3668   'PostCode::operator <': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods    (Error within the postcode class)
3. Error    C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    
4. Error    C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '&'    (3 + 4 = Errors within the interface)
```

I've read that the interface errors are due to type identifiers and i should declare them as static but this presents more error's. I am under the assumption that all methods within the interface are to be overridden as they declared pure virtual methods. (i.e = 0;). This isn't a void method because it returns values when implimented.

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can conclusively determine the problem, but only guess, at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Don't overload operators in abstract base classes.  Overload the operators in the child classes.

Comment: `PostCode` is not declared in the scope of `IPostCode` declaration. This error should be reported in the beginning of the error list.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i have updated the code content to my full code, can you provide a written example. Do you mean overload the method within main.cpp?

Comment: In your code, move `IPostCode::operator<` to your child class, i.e. the class(es) that inherits from `IPostCode`.  Or remove it entirely from the base class.

Comment: @S.M. The postcode class is inherited by the interface. i dont think the interface needs to declare the class. I have updated the interfaces code but has made no difference upon compilation. Thanks for the info

Comment: @ThomasMatthews so put the code in the main.cpp? main uses the interface which inherits the class.

Comment: Let me be more explicit.  Remove the `operator<` declaration from the class `IPostCode`.  Remove the keyword `virtual` from the `operator<` overload in class `PostCode`.

Comment: *i dont think the interface needs to declare the class* The compiler does not agree with you.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews bloody genius, thank you for the clear explanation also, i now understand that there is no override required for the bool. and the operator< method is not required as an interface method because it is a feature that the postcode class uses rather than the default behaviour of less than (<) operation. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not resolve all the compiler warnings and errors; only the `operator<`.
Remove the `operator<` declaration from class `IPostCode`:

```
class IPostCode
{

public:
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //  Remove the function below
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    virtual bool operator<(const PostCode& right) const = 0;

};
```

Remove the `override` keyword from the `PostCode` class:

```
class PostCode : public IPostCode
{

public:
    //---------------------------------------------------
    //   Remove "override" from the declaration below.
    //---------------------------------------------------
    bool operator<(const PostCode& right) const override;
};
```

You really don't want to override comparison operators or implement comparison functions in base classes.  When you have a pointer of the base class type, you don't know what kind of child class it really points to.  You could be comparing two different child classes.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Matthews, this has resolved the problem. Upvoted for helping me understand the problem also,